# Is it possible to get Asset attributes via REST API?

Tags: thingsboard

I checked that it's possible to get Device attributes thorough the devices-api-controller API, but I didn't find the API for getting Asset attributes. Our assets has attributes as coordinates and address that we want to inform to another system.

Is there an API for getting asset attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can abstract IoT entities for devices and assets.

The uri is `http(s)://host:port/api/asset`

You can find more information in the documentation at https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/entities-and-relations/